# Correlative numbers formula in Apple Numbers

Tags: numbers

I have text in column B. But there are some columns that are empty. There is no rule the empty raws are at random. This is what I have now:

[image: Before]

I want to have correlative numbers in column A. The problem is to detect the empty raws. That should be the result:

[image: After]

Comment: Do you want this as text is added? What if text is added in the middle, do you need the sequence of numbers to recalculate? If you could add a little more info about your process or how the data is added that would be helpful in finding a solution. In general, conditional formulas are your friend here. Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk: it is ok if the numbers are created after the text column. The other cases would be a plus. Can you put an example of the most basic case, please?

Comment: I would love to help, but if you could edit your question with more information.  Such as, is the text simply just added to random rows?  Is the empty row a result of inserting rows or deleting text?  As asked, it really difficult to advise the best approach. It makes a difference in how the spreadsheet is managed.  [You may want to learn more about using functions and formulas.](https://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/4.2/#/tan5ca02385) Cheers!

Comment: I updated the question. Text is in random rows. There is no inserting or deleting text. I already have all the text, and I need to create correlative numbers in column A

Comment: I'm just curious - do you need to keep the blank rows? For example, in your second image Column A has been populated based on the content in Column B, but all the rows that are blank in Column B (e.g. rows 3, 6, 7 etc) are still there. Is this by design (e.g. some of the other columns have data in these rows) or can you delete these rows altogether?

Comment: @Monomeeth: I need that rows. That is the key of my question. Here I put a simplified case. In real life in those empty rows there are titles o they are separations between blocks of information

Comment: All good! I always get concerned when people have totally blank rows in a spreadsheet list, but obviously that's not the case here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Enter a 1 in the cell A1.
2. Insert the following formula into cell A2.

   ```
   IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",MAX(A$1:A1)+1)
   ```

   This formula checks the cell to the right to see if it is blank. If it is blank, the cell in the A column should be blank too. If not, the cell should be filled with the next integer, which equates to the maximum integer reached so far + 1.
3. Fill the rest of the A column using this formula. Use the yellow fill handle so that the formula is adjusted correctly as it fills. The $ sign fixes the first cell of the range used by the MAX function.

[image]

Comment: It works very well. Clear and simple